# Blueimp Lightbox gallery angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to show image url from database on GUI with Blueimp Lightbox gallery but i get some error
Here is my html and js code:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeIn">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="lightBoxGallery">
                <div ng-repeat="i in images" class="col-sm-12 m-b-xs" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                    <a href="i.url" title="i.title" data-gallery="">
                      <img src="i.url">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- The Gallery as lightbox dialog, should be a child 
                     element of the document body
                -->
                <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
                    <div class="slides"></div>
                    <h3 class="title"></h3>
                    <a class="prev">‹</a>
                    <a class="next">›</a>
                    <a class="close">×</a>
                    <a class="play-pause"></a>
                    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular controller

```
.controller('ImagesCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams, ImagesService) {

    $scope.find = function() {
        ImagesService.find()
            .success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.images = data;
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                $.growl({ message: '<br>Getting data failed', title: '<b>ERROR</b>' }, { type: 'danger' });
        });
    }

    $scope.find();
});
```

as result on GUI i get list of objects in images variable, but it show me error for this i.url

> GET http://localhost:8080/i.url 404 (Not Found)

but when i go to network tab in browser i see this object and value inside variable url.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> <div ng-repeat="i in images" class="col-sm-12 m-b-xs" style="padding-left: 0px;">
>     <a href="i.url" title="i.title" data-gallery="">
>       <img src="i.url">
>     </a>
> </div>
> ```

The attributes need double curley brackets:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in images" class="col-sm-12 m-b-xs" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <a href="{{i.url}}" title="{{i.title}}" data-gallery="">
      <img src="{{i.url}}">
    </a>
</div>
```